# Does Python Crypto.Cipher directly take in hex data?

Tags: python-3.x, aes

The fundamental understanding of AES are:
1) 128-bit / 192-bit / 256-bit KEY
2) Data block size are 16 bytes / 128 bits
3) Cipher (encryted) text & plain text have the same length

However, when come to Python Crypto.Cipher AES implementation, KEY & DATA is represented in ASCII form. So, What if my raw data is in hexadecimal format? Must I convert them to ASCII format before passing it to the AES encryption? The same need to be apply to the KEY as well?

Some sample code I found, it shows the encrypted data can be converted to HEX form, but the inputs (KEY & PLAIN TETXT) is it must be in ASCII form?

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> a = AES.new("1234567890123456")
>>> m = 'aaaabbbbccccdddd'
>>> a.encrypt(m)
'H\xe7\n@\xe0\x13\xe0M\xc32\xce\x16@\xb2B\xd0'

>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(a.encrypt(m))
'48e70a40e013e04dc332ce1640b242d0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bytes.fromhex` should can easily achieve the objective.

Example:

```
b = AES.new((bytes.fromhex('31323334353637383930313233343536')))
print(binascii.hexlify(b.encrypt(m)))
```